# Power Bi - Get the average of the last X rows from a table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, calculated-columns, measure

I am currently in the process of learning myself, Power Bi. However, I got myself stuck when I tried to summarize a result based on the last X rows instead of filtering the last X dates. In order to have a better understanding here is the table that I created:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
Table name: Exampe<br><br>
<table><tbody><tr><th>Period</th><th>Value</th></tr><tr><td>2021 - W1</td><td>56.48%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W2</td><td>54.58%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W3</td><td>61.18%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W4</td><td>61.86%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W5</td><td>18.18%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W6</td><td>89.81%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W7</td><td>52.85%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W8</td><td>41.69%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W9</td><td>18.18%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W10</td><td>75.54%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W11</td><td>61.48%</td></tr><tr><td>2021 - W12</td><td>48.48%</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Where the result I am looking after should be the average percentage based on the last 6 rows instead of the entire column rows. Therefore, I ended up using "Measure" as I was not able to find a pre-build function for this in Power BI. My formula is the following:

```
Measure = Calculate(Average(Exampe[Value],TOPN(6,Exampe,[Value],Desc)
```

However, the output is incorrect. I would be really grateful if you can help me understand what I did wrong and why the formula is giving the wrong output. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the table as following, and you would like to get the average of last 6 row which is 750

[image]

In order to achieve the average last 6 row, first you need to create index column in query editor, after that using the following measure can achieve the expected output 750

```
Measure = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Sheet1[Value]),
            FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[Index] <= MAX(Sheet1[Index])
                 && Sheet1[Index] >MAX(Sheet1[Index]) -6))
```

This is how the table in Power Bi look like with index col, accept if help :)
[image]

Comment: Oh I see. However, I have one additional question. If we assume that the table would contain more values in the future would the power query editor be able to auto-populate the new rows or I have to rerun it again? 

Thank you so much for the provided solution. I am really grateful!

Comment: Add index column function in query editor will always auto incremental the index count, the most important part is that it can keep the order of the data. So every time you refresh your BI desktop, it should be provide correct result. Do some testing and see, if got issue then see how to solve it. Welcome, George.